# Why do some titles with MathJax go to a new line?

Tags: bug, mathjax, profile-page

When I look at my answers on my profile page [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/39599/michael-albanese?tab=answers), some of the titles with MathJax do not appear in a single line despite the fact that there is sufficient space. Some examples are

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19123/mathjax-v2-5-beta-released/19310#19310). (And also deleted post [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19309/titles-in-the-list-of-answers-divided-into-two-lines-in-a-strange-way) - visible for 10k+ users.)

Comment: Did you remember to sacrifice a goat to the Lords of MathJax? If not, it might be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the new update, this issue has been resolved.