# Some titles containing MathJax are shown incorrectly in review queues

Tags: bug, status-review, mathjax, review, titles

I have noticed, several times already, that some titles containing MathJax are rendered incorrectly in review queues, i.e. across multiple rows. I can't remember for sure, but I expect this to also happen on MathOverflow. The same titles display just fine in the "Stats" and "History" tabs of the review queues, on the main page and, of course, when the page containing the question is opened. I can also guarantee that the MathJax was error-free and basic in each case. Below is one such example. I believe that this is a bug; if the moderators share my opinion, I would appreciate if they forwarded this to the SE staff (MSE community managers).

**Important**: This bug shows up only when using the HTML-CSS renderer; the other renderers (Common HTML, Preview HTML, MathML) work just fine. ( I am using Firefox 92 for Windows 10.)

[image]

Comment: I've this this regularly in the review queues.  Thanks for posting.

Comment: This seems a bit similar to the bugs reported here: 
[Why do some titles with MathJax go to a new line?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19492),
[MathJax rendering issue while looking at someone's profile](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29728) and
[MathJax broken in "Related" section](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23073).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: It is a total mystery to all of us how you always manage to find them. I suspect that the *thing* behind your username is not a human; in particular, you probably fail all those CAPTCHA tests, haha! The weird thing is that, in all those discussions, reporting the issue led to it being fixed. Why does this bug still pop up?

Comment: @AlexM. In this case, I tried [searching using Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathjax+bug+site:math.meta.stackexchange.com&tbm=isch) - since I expected those posts to have screenshots. Yes, it is true that the past posts I linked say that it was fixed in those cases. Still, I thought that adding a link might be useful. (If nothing else, somebody more knowledgeable might be able to figure out whether the underlying reason might be the same.)